# CSS: Float div left next to table of arbitrary width?

Tags: css

I want to have a table (with an arbitrary number of columns) floated left, and some text floated left next to it if there is space, or down below it if there is not.

```
<div class="table">
<table>... table with arbitrary number of columns</table>
</div>
<div class="content">
Headings and paragraph text here (in a separate column, not flowing around the table)
</div>
```

I'd like the layout to be as follows:

[image]

I've started by just applying `{ float: left }` to both divs, but it's not working - the second div is always below the first. Why? I thought `float: left` should wrap text.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R9axt/1/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/R9axt/2/

Comment: Works fine in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from the `.visualisation-moreinfo` class as it will stretch it to the left below the table and there is no need to set `display:table` to a table

```
.visualisation-moreinfo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  /* float:left */ Removed */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9axt/3/)

Comment: I suggest using `min-width` to limit the size of the div, that means it's just pulled up when the space is large enough (such as about `100px`, so set `min-width:100px` for the div).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R9axt/6/). there is slight changes in your CSS. May solve your problem.

```
.visualisation-table {
  border: 1px solid blue;  
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
}

.visualisation-moreinfo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:48%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as the title says, the table needs to be of arbitrary width.